# Is it illegal for an adult to contact a minor if the minor's parents have instructed the adult not to do so?

Tags: united-states, minor

I am 17 yrs old and my parents have told my boyfriend and his parents not to contact me (and have told me not to contact them) because they disapprove and believe their family is causing me harm mentally and trying to turn me against my parents. However, my parents are misinterpreting and assume said family has malicious intentions, which is not true (their intentions are innocent and they genuinely intend to do no harm). They told his parents not to contact me, but I reached out to the parents and let them know that I would be willing to have a phone call with them so they could check in on how I was doing, which we have done once. Is it illegal for them to contact me if my parents told them not to, even though I initiated the contact and they were really just talking to me because they care to see how I am doing? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you? In some places you are a child in others you are an adult.

Comment: You seem to be confused over why your parents have done this. The motivation of your boyfriend and their family is irrelevant to what your parents perceive or what is actually happening, and forbidding contact for the perceived or actual effect doesn't depend on the motivation.

Comment: @DaleM I am in the US, and am considered a minor where I live.

Comment: @Nij  I am a little confused, yes, but I do know that they did this because of what they perceive the situation to be like. So from their perspective, it makes sense, but in terms of what it's actually like it doesn't feel like a just thing for them to do. The only problem is that it appears impossible to convince them otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Your parents have authority over you, and not other people. The courts, however, have authority over everyone, so your parents could petition the courts to order either the parents or the boyfriend to not contact you until you are 18. The courts would probably grant the petition, if the judge feels that it is in your best interest (based on the totality of facts). If a no-contact order is issued, then contact would be illegal.

Comment: The conditions for issuing a no contact order would typically be some sort of threat or imminent peril, not just that a parent asked for one.